# How to install Resynthesizer Plugin in GIMP snap?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, snap, plugins, gimp

I've installed a Gimp 2.10.6 snap on the Ubuntu 18.04 from the Ubuntu Store and I want to add the Resynthesizer plugin to it.

What I did is:

1. Downloaded the zip file from this GitHub repo:
   https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer
2. Extracted the python plugin scripts from:

   ```
   /home/aresminos/resynthesizer-master/PluginScripts
   ```

   to:

   ```
   /home/aresminos/snap/gimp/47/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins
   ```

Now when I try to use the **Filter > Enhance > Heal** Selection I get the following error popup:

> An error occurred running python_fu_heal_selection
> error: procedure not found
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/snap/gimp/47/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 740, in response
>     dialog.res = run_script(params)
>   File "/snap/gimp/47/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
>     return apply(function, params)
>   File "/home/aresminos/snap/gimp/47/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins/plugin-heal-selection.py", line 148, in heal_selection
>     pdb.plug_in_resynthesizer(timg, tdrawable, 0,0, useBorder, work_drawable.ID, -1, -1, 0.0, 0.117, 16, 500)
> error: procedure not found
> ```

Also I get this popup:

> GIMP Message
>
> Calling error for procedure 'gimp-procedural-db-proc-info':
> Procedure 'plug-in-resynthesizer' not found

And then I get this popup:

> GIMP Message
>
> Plug-in 'Heal selection' left image undo in inconsistent state, closing open undo groups.

How do I properly install the plugin?

Comment: Perhaps this plugin is not compatible with version 2.10 of Gimp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the Python files, but you're missing the main executables. Download and extract the zip files from https://www.gimp-forum.net/attachment.php?aid=1710

Comment: Extracting the zips from your source to `~/snap/gimp/47/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins` did the job. Thank you!

Comment: @Eroraf: great answer! Only a suggestion, could you edit your answer to include the relevant information instaed of relying in a link?

Comment: Thanks! I install Resynthesizer this way, but I don't found heal selection filter now. How can I get it?

Comment: Is there any updated guidance on this?