# GIMP Resynthesizer not working

Tags: gimp

I installed the resynthesizer plugin following the instructions on github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer. I downloaded resynthesizer.tar_0.gz from pixlsus's github moved the resynthesizer, resynthesizer_gui, and .py files to /home/USER/snap/gimp/322/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins and made the .py files executable (I also tried /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins).

When I attempt to use heal selection I get the following error:

Calling error for procedure 'gimp-procedural-db-proc-info': Procedure 'plug-in-resynthesizer' not found

This appears to be the same problem as http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16268 and [How to install Resynthesizer Plugin in GIMP snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072044/how-to-install-resynthesizer-plugin-in-gimp-snap). But both of those solutions involve running an executable from a random forum user. The files from bootchk's instructions are from 2011. Where is there an up-to-date resynthesizer?

Kubuntu 20.04 GIMP 2.10.18

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen hard and long way.

According to official [README](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) -

> If you want to install a package of third-party plugins (that includes Resynthesizer):
>
> Linux: install the package "gimp-plugin-registry" (available for most distributions, including Debian and Ubuntu).

So you need to install [single deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=resynthesizer) by

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

and then find Resynthesizer in the GIMP menus: Filters → Map → Resynthesize.